# It's possible to remove a group from rdlc dynamically?

Tags: rdlc

I have a rdlc file that get a data from my db.
I have put 3 groups, my question is if it's possible to remove 1 or more groups by expression?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "group", but you can right-click, select "Properties", then Visibility and "Show or hide based on an expression".

If you want to hide it if it only has one value you would do
    =Count(Fields!Name.Value, "Foo") > 0

Comment: Actually I am trying this too.. so I have seen the visibility option for the group based on an expression, however would anyone have an example say of hiding the group if only one grouped item is available?